# What is the deal with Daniel Jackson's sweater?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, clothing

During Season 6 of *Stargate SG-1* after Daniel Jackson has died and ascended, he appears multiple times in a variety of episodes. In the vast majority of these appearances he is wearing a cream/beige sweater.

This is the sweater I am talking about:

[image: Daniel Jackson in knitted sweater]

Prior to this point in the series I don't remember ever seeing him wear this sweater and I was wondering if it had any particular significance or if there is a known reason as to why his appearances as an ascended being feature this sweater?

Comment: Given the deific nature of the Ascended Ancients, I'd always assumed white was chosen as it represents the "Good Guys".  Beyond that, I never really thought about it.  Time to watch the series again and see if it mentions it. :D

Comment: Sweaters are cool.

Comment: It's the Godsweater. Bask in its glory.

Comment: It's an allusion to Steve Jobs being an Ancient

Comment: I forget which episode it was, but it might be sort of explained in the one where Daniel is in the diner with all the other Ascended Ancients.

Comment: Could just mean that you feel chilly when you ascend.

Comment: Good question. I remember Orlin looking fairly casual too when he was stalking Carter (all the other ascended beings seem to be wearing classical clothing). He also noted he could choose what he looked like, so for whatever reason, Daniel chose the sweater. My guess? It's comfy.

Comment: It's cold in the ascended-life.  Cable sweaters hide pokey reactions.

Comment: Whoops sorry for senseless editing, didn't realize that tag changes forcibly create revision entries before the 5-minute window ends.

Answer (score 5):

He [wore it](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Forever_in_a_Day#Notes) in "Forever in a day" (Season 3 episode 10) while attempting to resign from the SGC after the death of Sha're. Its significance may lie in there.

Comment: He wore a shirt under it in that episode, vs. post-ascension.

Comment: Daniel sweater fan-fic [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20050227124918/http://members.allstream.net/~jogall/sweater.htm).

Comment: That scene takes place entirely inside Daniel's head. The obvious conclusion is that the sweater doesn't actually exist; it's just what Daniel thinks of himself as wearing when he's not paying attention.